# Composer failure when installing Laravel + Voyager with league/flysystem

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, voyager, flysystem

I did a `composer create-project laravel/laravel .` and a `composer require tcg/voyager`.
I keep getting this.

```
Using version ^1.4 for tcg/voyager
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install tcg/voyager v1.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install tcg/voyager v1.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install tcg/voyager v1.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install tcg/voyager 1.x-dev
    - Conclusion: remove league/flysystem 1.1.0
    - Installation request for tcg/voyager ^1.4 -> satisfiable by tcg/voyager[1.4.x-dev, 1.x-dev, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.0
    - tcg/voyager 1.4.x-dev requires league/flysystem ~1.0.41 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.41, 1.0.42, 1.0.43, 1.0.44, 1.0.45, 1.0.46, 1.0.47, 1.0.48, 1.0.49, 1.0.50, 1.0.51, 1.0.52, 1.0.53, 1.0.54, 1.0.55, 1.0.56, 1.0.57, 1.0.58, 1.0.59, 1.0.60, 1.0.61, 1.0.62, 1.0.63, 1.0.64, 1.0.65, 1.0.66, 1.0.67, 1.0.68, 1.0.69, 1.0.70, 1.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.41, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.42, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.43, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.44, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.45, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.46, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.47, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.48, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.49, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.50, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.51, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.52, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.53, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.54, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.55, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.56, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.57, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.58, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.59, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.60, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.61, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.62, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.63, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.64, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.65, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.66, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.67, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.68, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.69, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.70, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.x-dev, 1.1.0].
    - Installation request for league/flysystem (locked at 1.1.0) -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I tried clearing the cache and starting the process over and also `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`. None of this seems to work.

I even tried installing flysystem before voyager like this discussion says:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/having-problems-with-laravel-53-voyager

Comment: It will be fixed once this PR is merged https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/pull/5040

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved on PR Merge.

https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/pull/5040

Voyager installs correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (when I run the command below):

```
>composer require league/flysystem-sftp
```

PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 Using version ^2.0 for league/flysystem-sftp ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.2
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.1
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.0
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.0-RC1
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.0-beta.3
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.0-beta.2
- league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.0-alpha.4 requires league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.3 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.3].
- league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.0-beta.1 requires league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.3 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.3].
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.3
- league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.0-alpha.3 requires league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.2 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.2].
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.2
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.20.3, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.20.3].
- league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.0-alpha.1 requires league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.1].
- league/flysystem-sftp 2.0.0-alpha.2 requires league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.1].
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.1
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem-sftp 2.x-dev|remove league/flysystem 1.1.3|install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.1|install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.2|install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.3
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem-sftp 2.x-dev|don't install league/flysystem 1.1.3|install league/flysystem
```

2.0.0-alpha.1|install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.2|install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.3
- Installation request for league/flysystem-sftp ^2.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-sftp[2.0.0, 2.0.0-RC1, 2.0.0-alpha.1,
2.0.0-alpha.2, 2.0.0-alpha.3, 2.0.0-alpha.4, 2.0.0-beta.1, 2.0.0-beta.2, 2.0.0-beta.3, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.x-dev].
- league/flysystem-sftp 2.x-dev requires league/flysystem ^2.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.0.0, 2.0.0-RC1, 2.0.0-alpha.1, 2.0.0-alpha.2, 2.0.0-alpha.3, 2.0.0-alpha.4, 2.0.0-beta.1, 2.0.0-beta.2, 2.0.0-beta.3, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.x-dev].

```
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.0.0, 1.1.3].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.0.0-RC1, 1.1.3].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.4, 1.1.3].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.0.0-beta.1, 1.1.3].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.0.0-beta.2, 1.1.3].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.0.0-beta.3, 1.1.3].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.0.1, 1.1.3].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.0.2, 1.1.3].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.x-dev, 1.1.3].
- Installation request for league/flysystem (locked at 1.1.3) -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.3].
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

---

**I have fixed the above error as follows:**

```
>composer require league/flysystem-sftp 1.*
```

Comment: "composer require league/flysystem-sftp 1.*" helped me install the package. Thank you @vansy